# React context with object value - Alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I've been working with a React context that takes in a `value` that is an **object**, and facing rerendering issues that I didn't understand fully until I saw this statement:

> If you are passing down an object on your React context provider and any property on it updates, what happens? Any component which consumes that context will re-render.

My question is... Is there an alternative to using a context when it comes to holding global state stuff in an object that will be updated?

Comment: You can use `useMemo` or you can create multiple contexts

Comment: @Konrad can you give me an example of how I might use `useMemo` in this case?

Comment: I have no idea how your code looks like

Comment: @Konrad https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-farrell-udxiwv